# Typing a function corresponding to a mapped type

Tags: typescript, function, properties, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I am trying to put together a utility function that allows me to reliably and type-safely map from one type of object to another, constrained by a mapped type and delivered by a mapping function that aligns with the mapped type.

I'm exercising it below to deliver the requirement to 'flatten' a tree of data to eliminate a level. So the result should be that...

```js
const CHARACTERS = {
  luke: { craft: ["xwing", "speeder"] },
  han: { craft: ["falcon", "eravana"] },
} as const;
```

Would be transformed to this data structure...

```js
const CRAFT = {
  luke: ["xwing", "speeder"],
  han: ["falcon", "eravana"],
} as const;
```

However, I can't seem to satisfy the type specification that reads `mapFn: <Key extends keyof From>(key: Key) => To[Key]`

What have I missed about the definition or implementation of mapFn to be able to define these operations and perform the transform without compiler errors?

```js
export function safeKeys<Lookup extends object>(lookup: Lookup) {
  return Object.keys(lookup) as (keyof Lookup)[];
}

export function mapFrom<
  From extends object,
  To extends { [K in keyof From]: any }
>(map: From, mapFn: <Key extends keyof From>(key: Key) => To[Key]) {
  const keys = safeKeys(map);
  return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key) => [key, mapFn(key)])) as {
    [K in keyof From]: To[K];
  };
}

const CHARACTERS = {
  luke: { craft: ["xwing", "speeder"] },
  han: { craft: ["falcon", "eravana"] },
} as const;

const CRAFT_BY_CHARACTER = mapFrom<
  typeof CHARACTERS,
  {
    [K in keyof typeof CHARACTERS]: (typeof CHARACTERS)[K]["craft"];
  }
>(CHARACTERS, (key) => CHARACTERS[key].craft); // the arrow function errors here
```

The error from the final arrow function reads like this, which from my reading IS in fact assignable to that type...

```
Type 'readonly ["xwing", "speeder"] | readonly ["falcon", "eravana"]' is not assignable to type '{ readonly luke: readonly ["xwing", "speeder"]; readonly han: readonly ["falcon", "eravana"]; }[Key]'
```

Comment: OK I can begin to see how it's not assignable, as `Key` is a loose type, so you might try to assign `["falcon", "eravana"]` to `"luke"` which would be Bantha poodoo. But I don't see how it became loose, and how and where I should bind it.

Comment: This is the issue discussed in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109); the compiler can't see the correlation across generic `K` for the operation `characters[key].craft` to be seen as type `CraftByCharacters[K]`; to do that you'd need an actual value of the output type and index into it directly (more like `intendedOutput[key]`).  You could refactor your types so that the generic operation is identical to what you're doing, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mq9R2m), but I don't know if it's worth it; you might just want to use type assertions.

Comment: ^ Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?